# How to validate only 7 digit number?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

I'm using mvc. So I want to validate user input number is 7 digit.

So I wrote a class.

```
 public class StduentValidator : AbstractValidator<graduandModel>
    {
        public StduentValidator(ILocalizationService localizationService)
        {                          
           RuleFor(x => x.student_id).Equal(7)
               .WithMessage(localizationService
                    .GetResource("Hire.graduand.Fields.student_id.Required"));                   
        }
```

But it is not working.
How to validate 7 digit numbers?

Comment: It seems you're using FluentValidation, that might be an important thing to mention.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Since you're using FluentValidation, you want to use the .Matches validator to perform a regular expression match.

```
RuleFor(x => x.student_id).Matches("^\d{7}$")....
```

Another option is to do something like this (if student_id is a number):

```
RuleFor(x => x.student_id).Must(x => x > 999999 && x < 10000000)...
```

Or, you could use the GreaterThan and LessThan validators, but the above easier to read.  Also note that if a number is something like 0000001 then the above won't work, you'd have to convert it to a string with 7 digits and use the technique below.

if student_id is a string, then something like this:

```
int i = 0;
RuleFor(x => x.student_id).Length(7,7).Must(x => int.TryParse(x, out i))...
```

Comment: @user1348351 - I keep forgetting about that, as it's not in the documentation for some reason...

Answer (score 3):

you can use `Regex` for that

```
bool x = Regex.IsMatch(valueToValidate, "^\d{7}$");
```

Comment: It seems this answer was posted 6 minutes before the officially accepted answer and is correct. I am curious why no votes to this and the one posted after 6 minutes got more votes!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **Must** extension. And convert value to string so you can use **.Length**

```
RuleFor(x => x.student_id).Must(x => x.ToString().Length == 7)
```

Comment: In case the **student_id** is an string, This way we cannot be sure if the inserted value is a number or text

Comment: Assuming the student_id is a number, given that the questions says "7 digit number".

Comment: It can be in some cases but it will require you to have another validation mechanism for checking to see If it is a number or not.